# In Tableview, How to get the textview value of selected row in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

How to get the textview value of selected row, i have search about this in google but not got proper solution.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    arr = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Apple",@"ms-dynamicsxrm://?etn=thk_store&pagetype=entityrecord&id=7b74df21-e5a0-e711-810a-5065f38a9b71",@"Micromax",@"Nokia", nil];
} 

#pragma mark - Table View Data source
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:  (NSInteger)section {
    return arr.count;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView  cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell_id";

    SecondTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: cellIdentifier];
    cell.label1.text = @"label";

    NSString *txtDetailStr = [arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if ([txtDetailStr containsString:@"ms-dynamicsxrm://"]) {
        NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:txtDetailStr attributes:@{ NSLinkAttributeName: [NSURL URLWithString:txtDetailStr] }];
        cell.textview1.attributedText = attributedString;
    } 
    else {
        cell.textview1.text = txtDetailStr;
    }
    return cell;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 100;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

}
```

How to get the textview value of selected row, i have search about this in google but not got proper solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get get the textview value of selected row inside `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` like this.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    SecondTableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSLog(cell.textview1.text);

    // If you want to get selected row data from your array then you can access it like this.
    NSString *txtDetailStr = [arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(txtDetailStr);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here i try with custom `UITableViewCell`

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}

    cell.textLabel.text = [self.tabledata objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;
```

//`indexPath.row` indicates which row is selected and it is set as label text